# JavaFX crashes X Server

Tags: javafx-2, xorg

Background/Context:

I'm currently developing a touch screen application which is aimed to run on Linux. As a development framework I chose JavaFX (jdk1.7.0_10) due to its rapid prototyping easiness. I'm using Arch Linux (kernel 3.6.10-1-ARCH) distribution and since JavaFX needs a head-full environment to run, I installed Xorg on top of the base configuration. Even thought I'm able to run my JavaFX application, I have some issues with popup windows that are being displayed in my application.

When trying to display those popup windows, sometimes they don't respond as expected or event worse, they crash my application. The error I get is the following:

```
The program 'java' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 51101 error_code 9 request_code 62 minor_code 0)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

By the way, when running the same application on Windows (my development machine), everything works fine.

I also tried to run a composite manager ('xcompmgr') since i was also getting some warnings like

```
Can't create transparent stage, because your screen doesn't support alpha channel. You need to enable XComposite extension.
```

but it didn't helped.

Question:

Am i missing some files or configurations in order to run smoothly JavaFX in Linux, or has any one encountered the same challenge? Since my main concern is performance (due to limited hardware specs), I don't want to install a full featured Linux distribution. I only need to run my JavaFX application.

Comment: I think you'll have more chance to get an answer if you ask this question on the openjfx-dev mailing list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev

Make sure to provide the corss-reference links here and in the mail, so people are aware of all answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what stack trace do you get in gdb if you follow the instructions given in the error message?

Answer (score 3):

Try running JavaFX in software rendering mode: `java -Dprism.order=j2d -jar your.jar`

Also note that your platforms seems to be not included into list of supported ones: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html