# showing an error when running javaFx application

Tags: javafx-2

I am running a javaFx application. When I click on some buttons it show the following error:

**Can't create transparent stage, because your screen doesn't support alpha channel. You need to enable XComposite extension.**

I am not able to find the problem. I almost spent an hour but still no output.
Please help.

Thanks on advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936573/javafx-crashes-x-server

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue for Linux systems without XComposite extension installed: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19700

Unfortunately you need to install XCompoiste extension to work with JavaFX applications using transparency.

Comment: Hi Sergey, how could I install XComposite extension? Actually I don't know much about Linux OS.

Comment: xcompmgr might support this. For Ubuntu, this is at http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xcompmgr