# Set Stage of ContextMenu and ColorPicker

Tags: java, linux, javafx, contextmenu, transparent

I have had a problem opening a `ContextMenu` or `ColorPicker` in some linux distributions without `xcompmgr`. Have managed to solve most problems using `Stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`

But these two elements continue to present problems and the message below:

> Can't create transparent stage, because your screen doesn't support
>   alpha channel. You need to enable XComposite extension.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing an error when running javaFx application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064944/showing-an-error-when-running-javafx-application)

Comment: Xcompmgr with the problem is solved, but I need that the application does not depend on transparency, because not all Linux distributions come with xcomposite installed.